# Multiple LM35 temperature sensors with summing amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, temperature, summing

I have two big heatsinks with four power MOSFETs on each of them, I want to control the temperature of each heatsinks so that doesn't exceed 80℃ using two [LM35](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) temperature sensors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS7grA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's no MCU involved and using another op amp I'll pulldown the MOSFETs gates when the limit is reached, the error up to 1-2℃ is acceptable.

Is this a good way to combine two sensors readings using analog circuitry or is there a better approach?

Comment: What power supplies are you using? Why use two LM35s per heatsink? One should do (per heatsink). How will you use the 2nd op-amp (crucial given your previous question)?

Comment: I think you gonna need a resistor to the GND at the R1/R2 node.

Comment: @Andyaka One sensor per heatsink. just using a comparator and another MOSFET.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1s1hR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let we have two voltage sources connected together trough resistors, as your idea. We then place a voltmeter which shows the average voltage of both sources (2+1)/2=1.5. But there is a difference between voltage source and LM35. The V1 would sink the current, while LM35 can't sink the current.

SOLUTION:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwbA71.png)</sup>

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't see the update to your answer.